# Click Handler doesn't work After Jquery POST

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page with a Select option and FORM, When a user changes selection, 
My jquery script function will dynamically do ajax POST to replace original form with different form (new form elements).

But i noticed that Click handler ($(button).click() Event) is not working on the newly generated form.
Please assist on this.

Is this a known problem in Jquery ??.

```
<select id=choice><option>....</select>
<div class=mytable>
<form id='dataform-10'>
.....
<button id="edit-10"></button>
</form>
<div>
<script>
  $(function(){
  $("#choice").change(function(){
    $.get('/portal/go?id='+this.value, function(data, status){ 
            //$(".mytable").hide();
            $(".mytable").html(data);
            $(".mytable").show();
          });
  });
});
</script>
<script>
$('[id^=edit]').on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   var num = this.id.slice(5);   
   var fdata = $('#dataform-'+num).serialize();
   $.post('/portal/update', fdata, function(data, status){ 
            alert(data);
          });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6658774/2182949

Comment: You haven't added any code. Edit your question with _the relevant code_ only as a [mcve].

Comment: I have Added Code above. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: You're rebuilding mytable, so the `[id^=edit]` buttons that had the event attached no longer exist.  You need to see event delegation.  See the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out by @sh977218 the reason why the click event does not work is the addition of new elements in DOM after the initial tagging of event handlers. Try something like this:

```
<script>
function clickEventHandler(event) {
  // code for click event 
   event.preventDefault();
   var num = event.target.id.slice(5);   
   var fdata = $('#dataform-'+num).serialize();
   $.post('/portal/update', fdata, function(data, status){ 
        alert(data);
      });
}
$('[id^=edit]').on("click", function(e){clickEventHandler(e);});
$("#choice").change(function(){
  $.get('/portal/go?id='+this.value, function(data, status){ 
        //$(".mytable").hide();
        $(".mytable").html(data);
        $(".mytable").show();
        $('[id^=edit]').on("click", function(e){clickEventHandler(e);});
      });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Not working. My JSfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/tLerb2n6/ , Try to click on Second button pls.

Comment: You are still not using a named function try this https://jsfiddle.net/4eq5c81s/

Comment: I got the event to catch now, But unfortunately this line    var num = this.id.slice(5); is not working. Error is Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined

Comment: try using event.target.id instead

Answer (score 0):

When your add some new DOM, you need to hook the event on it again.

Answer (score 0):

... `$('[id^=edit]').on("click",function(e) {` ...

should be

... `$(".mytable").on("click", "[id^=edit]", function(e) {` ...

Have you tried like this?

Comment: Tried that No luck, Instead of catching Click event, form redirects me

Comment: Are you sure you have the `e` parameter in the handler function and the         `e.preventDefault();` afterwards?

Comment: Yes I have ,function(e) {    e.preventDefault();

Comment: Hm.. can't really help without a playground example. Would it be possible for you to create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) which illustrates the problem?

Comment: This won't work because `.mytable` is not a *child* of `[id^=edit]`.  Maybe swap them around? (or just use `$(document).on("click", "[id^=edit]", function...`)

Comment: @freedomn-m sure, my bad, thanks for pointing this out. I've edited my answer.